# How to handle singularly the last n records of a column in a mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database MySQL like this:

```
 ------------------------
 | id |  Name  |  City  |
 ------------------------
 | 1  | John   | London |
 | 2  | Jim    | N.York |
 | 3  | Annie  | Rome   |
```

By the following query I retrieve the last n data of a specific column:

> SELECT id, Name, City FROM mytable ORDER by id DESC limit
>   0,2

in this case I retrieve the last two records from the columns "id" , "Name" and "City"

How can i associate a specific variable in php to each name of my result?

For example: 
$n1 = Annie
$n2 = Jim

So i'll be able to use each single element of the resulting query for my needs in the following part of my php code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have already the results fetched as array you can do this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($results); $i++) {
    $n{$i} = $results[$i-1];
}
```

the result in this case will be:

```
$n1 = array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Annie'...);
$n2 = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jim');
```

or you can do:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($results); $i++) {
    $n{$i} = $results[$i-1]['name'];
}
```

and in this case the result will be:

```
$n1 = 'Annie';
$n2 = 'Jim';
```

but the real question is, why not use the results array itself?

Comment: Hi Jeffey, I try explain me better. I have to generate an xml file which has inside some data picked up from a Mysql database. In particular, I need to associate to different variables the last n records of a column. So I will be able to write with my xml file by calling the php script that i'm working to realize. In other words I need to handle $n1...$n2... which will write a different value in the xml file. thx in advance for your reply. Mat

Comment: @mattew, doesn't any of the two answers provided you solve your problem?